# Excel 2013: how to format a column of cells to a predetermined amount of digits with auto-fill

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm new here and apologize if this is a noob question, but i've spent a solid 20 minutes trying to find a solution online, or previous question similar to this. I have a large inventory data dump from a supplier that I want to import into my system. The problem is all the numbers in the "vendorpart#" column are 5 or 6 digits depending on the part number. However, the part number sequence needs to be 10 digits, no more no less, with the balance as zeros infront. example (0000123456, or 0000012345).

Below is a link to a sample of the cells I've filled in some of them for example manually but have thousands more too go.
rather than doing this manually, there has to be a function or cell format that can auto-fill this for me? Any suggestions would be immensely appreciated.

VendorPart Number example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7310nlmeafdb3g/Vendor%20PN.JPG?dl=0&m=

Formula Bar value not matching the cell value: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bbwskm1nl95a4pp/Formula%20bar%20value.png?dl=0&m=

Comment: Highlight the column, then go to formatting - that should do it

Comment: Choose Format>Cells...  Select Custom under Category, and enter a custom format of 00000#####.  That's 5 zeros and five number signs.

Comment: You don't need to create a duplicate column unless you really want to.  You can apply the format to your vendor part# column.

Comment: Thanks Bandersnatch. That is a much faster approach. I ran that through to autofill the column and it worked great. I did a test import and ran into a problem. The value of the cell inside the formula bar for the cells i filled in manualy is "0000012345". However even though the cells i applied the formatting 0000###### to look good on the sheet, they only display the true number "123456" without the zeroes in front in the formula bar. On my test import it pull the number from the formula bar so I'm back where i was again

any thoughts on how to have it change inside the formula bar as well?

Comment: Here is another link to a sample of the problem: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bbwskm1nl95a4pp/Formula%20bar%20value.png?dl=0&m=

Comment: @JFurm, what I've realized that in particular Data Range you want 10 Zeros to display and when you import Part number must adjust the value and display Leading Zeros also, or Format for 10 Zeros and after Data imported show Leading Zeros?

Comment: @RajeshS Yes that is corrrect, thank you for providing an alternative solution below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have described in the Query that you are handling 10 digits value and you want Excel to display **Leading Zeros** if, value is less than 10 digits. In this case you need to do the followings,

1. Select the Data Range.
2. Click Cell Format Icon.
3. Select the Custom.
4. Write 0000000000.
5. Hit the Ok.

**Check the Screen Shot**,

[image]

Or you can use the this one also, =Text(A2,"0000000000")

**NB:** This is the Most easiest way to handle Value with Leading Zeros.

Comment: This answer also works well, just have to paste the values and it imports perfectly. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

In a free column put the following formula, referring to a part number instead of L15 (appears twice in the formula):

```
=REPT("0",10-(ROUNDDOWN(LOG(L15),0)+1))&L15
```

This will make a text field with the right number of leading zeros.

Comment: Awesome, that is quite the formula and it works perfectly! thank you so much!

Comment: great. remember to 'accept' the answer if it works for you